# I want to implement a Simple Columnar Transposition in cpp. I am having the problem with the encryption part in cipher() function. (without using stl)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string cipher(string s);
int main()
{
string s = "";
getline(cin, s);
cout << cipher(s);
return 0;
}
string cipher(string s)
{
int row, col, i, j, m, n, k = 0, o = 0;
string cipher = "";
int key_order[] = {3, 5, 4, 2, 1};

cout << "Length of String:" << s.length() << endl;
cout << "Enter the number of columns" << endl;
cin >> col;
// cout<<col<<endl;

row = s.length() / col;
if (s.length() % col)
{
    row += 1;
}
cout << "Row:" << row << endl;

char arr[row][col];

// storing string values in a 2d array
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = s[k];
        k++;
    }
}

// Encrypting the message
for (m = 0; m < col; m++)
{
    for (n = 0; n < row; n++)
    {
        cipher = arr[n][(arr[n][m] + (key_order[o] - 1))];
    }
    o++;
}
cout << cipher;

return cipher;
// char arr[][col];
}
```

I am using 2 loops outer one for incrementing columns and inner for incrementing rows. arr[n][(arr[n][m] + (key_order[o] - 1))]; this code does that it will take the nth row and for column it will take a particular column of a row then add it with the key_order array it will give a the resultant element of the array and display the result.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It may be that `cipher = arr[n][(arr[n][m] + (key_order[o] - 1))];` should use a `+=` instead, but there may be other issues. Please also indicate the sample data you use.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? What does it do instead? Please show the input, expected output and actual output. `s[k]` may go outside the bounds of the string